# Not receiving push notification after firebase dependancy upgrade

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-12

we have raised our targetSDKVersion to 31 (android 12).
We end up getting following crash in firebase library. So we decided to upgrade our firebase version to latest to avoid it. We need help with properly migrating to new version. In earlier version we use FirebaseInstanceId to get token with projectNumber and register it with Notification service.

```
private static final String projectNumber = "335085002068";
> @Override
> protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
> String registrationID = null;
> try {
> FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
> registrationID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(projectNumber, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
> catch (Exception exp) {
> Log.e(TAG, "firebase Instance ID exception", exp);
>     }
> _delegate.onCompletion(registrationID);
> return null;
> }
```

FirebaseInstanceId is not available in newer versions, instead we tried to use FirebaseMessaging.getToken() and FirebaseInstallations but none of these APIs take projectNumber as attribute. Using FirebaseMessaging.getToken() and registering is not working.

```
> FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
>     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
>         @Override
> public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
> if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
> Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
> return;
>           }
> 
> Get new FCM registration token
> String token = task.getResult();
> 
> Log and toast
> String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
> Log.d(TAG, msg);
> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>   });
```

Can  anyone who encountered this in upgrading firebase please help us out here?
How to unlink projectNumber with our app with Notifcation service?

Upgraded to latest and try different solution from stackoverflow but nothing is woking
Looking for a solution or help

Comment: I don't understand why you want to pass the projectNumber as a parameter. You just need to save the token to send notifications in the future, in case you want the user information about the user, you must enable analytics.

Comment: I don't want to send notification I just want to receive it

Comment: When you say "Using FirebaseMessaging.getToken() and registering is not working" what do you mean? do you get errors? Is it not returning the token?